# Menu text change color on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to make my menu text change color when someone scrolls down. Here is the website https://patrolpoints.com. For example when you scroll down on our other site https://www.condocontrolcentral.com the menu color changes from white to black. I would like to do the same thing

I have tried adding this code that makes the header wrap change from transparent to white. added the site title class but it only change the background

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 500) {       
        jQuery(".site-title").addClass("fixedtxt");
    } else

    {
        jQuery(".site-title").removeClass("fixedtxt");
    }
}); 
</script> 

<style>
.site-title.fixedtxt{
background-color:#000000;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please, post your code to show what you tried so far.

Comment: You must also note that the nav-bar itself also changes to white when the menu turns to black. So two effects are triggered. Try my code below with your existing html code.

Comment: I added the code I was trying to use

Answer (score 0):

```js
        (function()
        {
            var setPoint = 50;
            var headerElement = document.getElementById("header");
            var ReferenceElement = document.getElementById("page");

            function ToggleHeader(setValue, currentPosValue)
            {
                if(currentPosValue > setValue)
                {
                    headerElement.style.color = "black";
                    headerElement.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                }else{
                    headerElement.style.color = "white";
                    headerElement.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
                }
            }
            
            ReferenceElement.onscroll = function()
            {
                ToggleHeader(setPoint, ReferenceElement.scrollTop);
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Scroll pos is: " + ReferenceElement.scrollTop;
            }
        }());
```

```css
body, html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
    <div id="page"
        style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: scroll;">
        <header id="header"
                style=" color: white; 
                        height: 72px;
                        width: 100%;
                        background-color: transparent;
                        position: fixed;
                        top: 0;
                        line-height: 72px;
                        ">
            <a>Company Logo</a>
            <a>Some Link 1</a>
            <a>Some Link 2</a>
            <a>Some Link 3</a>
            <a>Some Link 4</a>
            <a id="text"></a>
        </header>
        <Section    role="main"
                    id="section" 
                    style=" height: 1800px; 
                            padding: 72px;
                            width: 100%; 
                            background-color: #d1d1d1;">
            <h1>
                Change Header Colors when this passes the header
            </h1>
            <p>Some Text</p></br />
            <p>Some Text</p></br />
            <p>Some Text</p></br />
            <p>Some Text</p></br />
            <p>Some Text</p></br />
            
        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is the code I was trying to use <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 500) {       
            jQuery(".site-title").addClass("fixedtxt");
        } else
        
        {
            jQuery(".site-title").removeClass("fixedtxt");
        }
    }); 
</script> 

<style>
.site-title.fixedtxt{
    background-color:#000000;
}
</style>

Comment: You're complicating it buy adding classes and removing classes. Just use Javascript to change the actual style properties. Much easier. But the logic is pretty much like what I had suggested.  Let me work it out with an html code and I'll post snippets now now!

Comment: Ok thank you! i am not good at java script or coding in general

Comment: I just did a quick solution - you're welcome to implement the same logic your way.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesnt seem to be working on my website

Comment: Did you run the snippet?

Comment: The snippet work, But i brought the code over to my site and it did not work  https://patrolpoints.com I am not sure what I did wrong

Comment: are you testing on firefox?

Comment: Some browsers has problems with positioning, use Jquery for cross browser compatibility

Comment: I am testing on chrome . How do i use jquery with  the code you gave me? It doesnt work with firefox either

Comment: I am not sure if I added the correct ID. 
 var headerElement = document.getElementById("masthead");
            var ReferenceElement = document.getElementById("page");

Comment: It will depend on how you renamed your id's